# Shouldn't lower_bound return an iterator pointing to end()?

Tags: c++, lower-bound

I am trying to understand `lower_bound` better.  I have the code below:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
 
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> data = { -1,0,3,5,9,12 };
 
        auto lower = std::lower_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), -2);
 
        if (lower != data.end())
            std::cout << *lower << " at index " << std::distance(data.begin(), lower);
        else
            std::cout << "not found";
        std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Note that this is just a sample code modified from cppreference.com.  Per the documentation there:

> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range [first, last) that is not less than (i.e. greater or equal to) value, **or last if no such element is found**.

Given that the element I am looking for `-2` isn't present in the vector `data`, I expect `lower_bound` to set `lower==data.end()`.  However, [what I get](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=42814155d3b86d1b) is:

> -1 at index 0

instead.  Could someone please explain *why*?

Many thanks!

Comment: Is something unclear about _Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range **that is not less than (i.e. greater or equal to)**_ - that reads like it will point to the first element greater than _value_ (i.e. -2)

Comment: Well, what about the remainder of that sentence - _or last if no such element is found_?  In my case the element (`-2`) is not found.

Comment: _if no such element is found_ i.e if no element that is greater or equal to `-2` is found, then yes it will return `end`. Here, there _is_ an element that is greater than or equal to `-2`. Namely: all of them - so it returns the first one, per the documentation

Comment: Ah, ok!  I thought they meant if `-2` (the element) itself is not found!

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to remember how `std::lower_bound` works is that it will return an iterator to the place where an item should be inserted to retain the sorted order.  In your case that would be the beginning of the sequence.

Comment: Thank. you for your answer!  Although, my question was mainly what @Tas talked about in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62907069/shouldnt-lower-bound-return-an-iterator-pointing-to-end#comment111244161_62907069).